# Change the <input> button to a hyperlink tag <a>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I need to change my avatar image, and after pressing the Change picture button select the image and after that have a preview of new added photo. Here is my code:

**.html**

```
<!-- Avatar -->
<div class="avatar avatar-xl mb-6">
    <img class="rounded-circle account-img" id="id_image_display" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}"  alt="...">
</div>
<div class=" mb-6 mt-7 ml-2">
    <div class="form-group image-group" id="id_image_group">
        <a href="" id="upload_avator_link">
           <b>Change picture</b>
        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="group-input">
         <input type="file" name="image" id="upload_avator" accept="pics/*" onchange="readURL(this)">
    </div>


</div>
```

This is the Js function:

**.js**

```
     document.getElementById('id_image_group').onclick = function(event){
          document.getElementById('upload_avator').click();
     };

     function readURL(input){
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onload = function (e) {
             $('#id_image_display')
                 .attr('src', e.target.result)
         };
         reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     }
```

and this is the `.css` code:

```
#upload_avator_link{
    text-decoration:none;
}
#upload_avator{
    display:none
}
```

It should work but it doesn't! Any kind of help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<a href...>` tag is trying to navigate.  Try changing to:

```
<a id="upload_avator_link">
```

If you want the text to look like a hyperlink, you can style it as desired.  You can get rid of the `<a>` tag and just style the parent div.

Also, you might want to wrap your `<input... />` field in a `<form>...</form>` tag for full browser compatibility.